# How to merge questions instead of closing one or more of them?

Tags: support, merge

I read that concurrent questions can be merged instead of closing one or more of them. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To request that a question be merged, please click the flag button and explain why, then a moderator will merge it if needed.

For more info, see this. [Are there guidelines on direction for merging questions (which question to close/merge?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107846/are-there-guidelines-on-direction-for-merging-questions-which-question-to-close)